# Vue - Render components depending on state of parent data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to render components depending on the state of an array in the parent (App.vue). I'm not sure at all that this is the correct approach for this use case (new to Vue and not experienced programmer) so I will gladly take advice if you think this is not the right way to think about this.

I'm trying to build a troubleshooter that consists of a bunch of questions. Each question is a component with data that look something like this:

```
data: function() {
    return {
        id: 2,
        question: "Has it worked before?",
        answer: undefined,
        requires: [
            {
                id: 1,
                answer: "Yes"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This question is suppose to be displayed if the answer to question 1 was yes.

My problem is I'm not sure on how to render my components conditionally. Current approach is to send an event from the component when it was answered, and to listen to that event in the parent. When the event triggers, the parent updates an array that holds the "state" of all answered questions. Now I need to check this array from each component to see if there are questions there that have been answered and if the right conditions are met, show the question.

My question is: How can I check for data in the parent and show/hide my component depending on it? And also - is this a good idea or should I do something different?

Here is some more code for reference:

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="c-troubleshooter">
            <one @changeAnswer="updateActiveQuestions"/>
            <two @changeAnswer="updateActiveQuestions"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import one from './components/one.vue'
import two from './components/two.vue'

export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
        one,
        two
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            activeQuestions: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateActiveQuestions(event) {
            let index = this.activeQuestions.findIndex( ({ id }) => id === event.id );
            if ( index === -1 ) {
                this.activeQuestions.push(event);
            } else {
                this.activeQuestions[index] = event;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

two.vue

```
<template>
    <div v-if="show">
        <h3>{{ question }}</h3>
        <div class="c-troubleshooter__section"> 
            <div class="c-troubleshooter__input">
                <input type="radio" id="question-2-a" name="question-2" value="ja" v-model="answer">
                <label for="question-2-a">Ja</label>
            </div>
            <div class="c-troubleshooter__input">
                <input type="radio" id="question-2-b" name="question-2" value="nej" v-model="answer">
                <label for="question-2-b">Nej</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            id: 2,
            question: "Bla bla bla?",
            answer: undefined,
            requires: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    answer: "Ja"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        show: function() {
            // Check in parent to see if requirements are there, if so return true
            return true;
        }
    },
    watch: {
        answer: function() {
            this.$emit('changeAnswer', {
                id: this.id,
                question: this.question,
                answer: this.answer
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try putting all the question data into the parent and passing it to the children as props. The child component can probably be made into a generic question component you can use for all questions. `requires` can be a function. If I have some time later I will write up an answer.

Comment: Yeah I realise it's weird to have a component for each question, but I'm not really sure how modular I can do them since the template for each question can be a bit different. Some have images or custom elements in them for example, while others don't. That said, most of these components are basically similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question, but I'll try to give some useful guidance.

First `data` should be used for *internal* state. Very often, a component should use `props` for things you might think would be `data` it owns. That is the case here: the questions need to be coordinated by the parent, so the parent should own the data. That allows you to make a sensible function to control whether a question component displays.

Having the parent own the data also allows you to make one question component that configures itself according to its props. Or you might have a few different question component types (you can use [`:is`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) to select the right one), but almost certainly some of them are reusable if you pass their question/answer/other info in.

To update answers, you will emit changes from the question components and let the parent actually change the value. I use a settable computed to allow the use of `v-model` in the component.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      questions: [{
          id: 1,
          question: 'blah 1?',
          answer: null
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          question: 'blah 2?',
          answer: null,
          // this is bound because data is a function 
          show: () => {
            const q1 = this.questions.find((q) => q.id === 1);

            return Boolean(q1.answer);
          }
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          question: 'Shows anyway?',
          answer: null
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  components: {
    questionComponent: {
      template: '#question-template',
      props: ['props'],
      computed: {
        answerProxy: {
          get() {
            return this.answer;
          },
          set(newValue) {
            this.$emit('change', newValue);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="c-troubleshooter">
    <question-component v-for="q in questions" v-if="!q.show || q.show()" :props="q" @change="(v) => q.answer = v" :key="q.id">
    </question-component>
  </div>
  <h2>State</h2>
  <div v-for="q in questions" :key="q.id">
    {{q.question}} {{q.answer}}
  </div>
</div>

<template id="question-template">
  <div>
    {{props.question}}
    <div class="c-troubleshooter__input">
        <input type="radio" :id="`question-${props.id}-a`" :name="`question-${props.id}`" value="ja" v-model="answerProxy">
        <label :for="`question-${props.id}-a`">Ja</label>
    </div>
    <div class="c-troubleshooter__input">
        <input type="radio" :id="`question-${props.id}-b`" :name="`question-${props.id}`" value="nej" v-model="answerProxy">
        <label :for="`question-${props.id}-b`">Nej</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I realise it's a broad question, sometimes the problems you have are just not that specific though. Thanks a lot for your feedback, it helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

#### Rendering questions conditionally

as @Roy J suggests in comments, questions data probably belongs to the parent. It is the parent who handles all the data and who decides which questions should be rendered. However, there are plenty of strategies for this:

1. Display questions conditionally with `v-if` or `v-show` directly in the parent template:

Maybe the logic to display some questions is not at all generic. It can depend upon more things, user settings... I don't know. If that's the case, just render the questions conditionally directly in the parent, so you don't need to access the whole questions data in any question. Code should be something like the following:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="c-troubleshooter">
            <one @changeAnswer="updateActiveQuestions" v-if="displayQuestion(1)"/>
            <two @changeAnswer="updateActiveQuestions" v-if="displayQuestion(2)"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import one from './components/one.vue'
import two from './components/two.vue'

export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
        one,
        two
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            activeQuestions: [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateActiveQuestions(event) {
            let index = this.activeQuestions.findIndex( ({ id }) => id === event.id );
            if ( index === -1 ) {
                this.activeQuestions.push(event);
            } else {
                this.activeQuestions[index] = event;
            }
        },
        displayQuestion(index){
          // logic...
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

2. Pass a reference to the previous question to every question:

If any question should be visible only when the previous question has been answered or viewed or something like that, you can pass that as a prop to every question, so they know wether they must render or not:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="c-troubleshooter">
            <one @changeAnswer="updateActiveQuestions"/>
            <two @changeAnswer="updateActiveQuestions" prev="activeQuestions[0]"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And in `two.vue`:

```
props: ['prev'],
computed: {
    show: function() {
        return this.prev && this.prev.status === 'ANSWERED';
        // or some logic related to this, idk

    }
},
```

3. just pass the whole data to the children:

As you coded it, you can just pass the whole questions data as a prop to every question component, then use it in a computed property. This is not what I would do, but just works, and since objects are references this is not necessarily unperformant.

#### Using a generic  component:

It seems weird to have a `one.vue`, `two.vue` for every question, and sure does not scale well.

> I'm not really sure how modular I can do them since the template for each question can be a bit different. Some have images or custom elements in them for example, while others don't.

If template are **really different** from each question to another, this can get complicated. However, if, as I suspect, they share common HTML structure, with a defined header or a common 'ask' button at the bottom and stuff like that, then you [should be able to address this using Vue slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html).

Apart from template issues, I suppose that every question in your app can get an arbitrary number of 'sub-questions' (as `two.vue` having `question-2-a` and `question-2-b`). This will require a complex and flexible data structure for the questions data (which will get more complex when you start to add multiple choices, multiple possible answers etc. etc.). This can get very complex but you should probably work on this until you can use a single `question.vue` component, this will surely pay out.

#### tip: avoid watchers

You're using `v-model` to `answer` in the `two.vue` template, then using a watcher to track changes in the `answer` variable and emit the event. This is convoluted and difficult to read, you can use `@input` or `@change` events on the `<input>` element instead:

```
<input type="radio" id="question-2-a" name="question-2" value="ja" v-model="answer" @input="emitAnswer">
```

And then instead of the watcher, have a method:

```
emitAnswer() {
this.$emit('changeAnswer', {
    id: this.id,
    question: this.question,
    answer: this.answer
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for these tips, very helpful!